File permissions in container, built with spring-boot-maven-plugin build-image-no-fork
I'm moving from a classic jar deployment to a containerized deployment of my java 21 application.
For that purpose I like to create my container image with spring-boot-maven-plugin with the goal build-image-no-fork. Currently using all standard settings.
So far so good. The image gets built and the container starts up.
But while running I have issues with permissions inside the container. Logfiles (in the container) or disk persisted ehcache files are not able to be created: File permission issues.
I know, that logifles and these cache files should not be inside the container, but for migration purposes, this is a temporary requirement.
Is there a way to adjust user permissions for the app running in the container?

Show your Dockerfile and application.properties.

he's not using a Dockerfile though - but the end result is still an OCI image using Paketo buildpacks

@alexander specifically wrote "spring-boot-maven-plugin with the goal build-image-no-fork"
So he's using Paketo Buildpacks: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/maven-plugin/build-image.html and references to Dockerfile are quite irrelevant in this context, it's a competing technology to build OCI images
